# utf8_encode post-variables if it contains special characters (æøå)

Tags: php, post, encoding

I've got the following problem.

When a form is submitted using ajax I need to check a few of the POST-variables if they contain the special characters æ, ø and å (as well as uppercase Æ Ø Å). Say I have 100 POST-variables, I really only care about a few of them (say firstname, lastname and adress). If it contains these letters the content of the variable should be utf8_encoded.

How can this be done in a nice dynamic way? I need to be able to change what variables I am checking easily (I guess the best way is to store this in an array).

Are there any neat ways to do this, or do I have to have a mess of loops in order to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the encoding of your page? are you sending the content-type header with charset=utf-8? do you also have a content-type meta tag as a backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
$str = 'áéóú';
mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true); // false
```

Ref: [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)